# Extract name from LDAP path using regular expression

Tags: regex, ldap

Currently I'm using the regular expression below to extract names from the LDAP paths, it works fine until a comma has been used in the path.

Current regex:

```
CN=([^,]*).*
```

In the example LDAP path below I get "Deborah\" and I would like it to return "Deborah, James". I don't understand regular expressions and I have spent hours trying to make this work, can anyone help me solve this?

CN=Deborah\, James,OU=Staff,DC=Comp,DC=com

Much appreciated.
Jake

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a controlled environment and can control that CN will always be found by OU, then you can do use this:

```
CN=(.*),OU=
```

If you can't guarantee that then you can use this which is a little more complicated but will work if any other attribute follows CN or if CN is last:

```
CN=(.*?)(?:,[A-Z]+=|$)
```

Comment: Thanks for that but both these leave me with

Comment: Deborah\, JamesStaff,DC=Comp,DC=com

Comment: Sorry about that, somehow clicked Add Comment before I was finished, as you can see above it doesn't work, perhaps I am doing something wrong. Does this work for you? Thanks

Comment: @jakeHolt:  Then modify it to be ,DC= at the end, instead of OU= (Also turn off case sensitivity, since it as likely to be ou= or dc=).  Realize that period, comma, and slashes will be escaped the same way.

Comment: @JakeHolt, yes, it worked for me with the test data you provided in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the LDAP API for parsing names, not regular expressions. In Java JNDI this means getting a NameParser from the Context.

Comment: Not all LDAP API's provide this functionality.  .NET's DirectoryServices APIs unfortunately do not (although they have an internal class for it, but it's not exposed publicly).  The OP didn't say what technology he was using.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the other answers listed here but they still returned the values outside of the common name.  I didn't want a group so this is what I came up with.  It will work if the CN inside a DN or OU.

(?i:(?<=CN=)).*?(?=,[A-Za-z]{0,2}=|$)